# Accessing Machine level configuration with Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, registry

I am new to Linux and working with Mono.

As i migrate from windows so first search is for something like the Windows registry in Linux. I come to know here is no registry available, instead there is a configuration file for each program.

I have some more questions...

1. I want to read some Machine Level information, how this is possible...?
2. I want to change a permission of a file with mono program written in c# using syscall.chmod. Is this possible, can change the permission of machine level configuration files..?

Waiting for your prompt reply, if something is not clear please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You mostly need to look in the /etc folder for configuration of just about every system service. Though depending on your linux distribution, there will be some quite major differences.
2. So long as your program is running with root privs, you should be able to chmod any file. I'm not familiar with syscall.chmod, but it should work.

Comment: Thanx for rply. It means when i call some registry key from my program it will read some configuration file and then will return me the result. MONO will handle underlying complexity by self; means i can call registry key per user registries or machine level if not what will be the case.

Comment: No, this does not work this way. There's no way to map Windows registry keys to Unix configuration files.

Comment: Pretty much, and given there's not a lot of similarity between some core configuration files for each distro, you will be in for a lot of pain. Do you really need to edit system files? You know there's probably a reason why things where configured the way they were in the first place.